# Python .split() not working in my program when using a determiner

Tags: python

I am trying to create a music guessing game whereby the **FULL NAME** of the artist is given and the first letter of **EACH WORD** of the title is given. My current code (that works) is capable of handling one word for the artist and one word for the song; for example EDEN Nocturne.

However, if the artist were to have two parts in their name (Ed Sheeran) my code wouldn't be able to handle this (similarly to the song name).
Therefore, I wanted to use a determiner to split the artist and song so that I could print the whole Artist name and then use the **try:** and **except:** functions to be able to print the first letter of each word of the song if it is available.

When I just use a space the .split() function works correctly, however when I use a word or a symbol ('DOT', '|') It no longer works.

This is the code that works:

```
with open('MusicNames.txt') as file:
    text = file.readlines()[number]
    artist = text.split()[0]
    print('Artist: ' + artist)
    song = text.split()[1]
    songLetter = text.split()[1][0]
    print('First letter: ' + songLetter)
```

The code above works for this style of Artist and Song:

[image: The code above works for this style of Artist and Song]

However, it will not work in this instance:

[image: However, it will not work in this instance]

Hence, I use a determiner as such:

```
with open('MusicNames.txt') as file:
    text = file.readlines()[number]
    artist = text.split('|')[0]
    print('Artist: ' + artist)
    song = text.split('|')[1]
    songLetter = text.split('|')[1][0]
    print('First letter: ' + songLetter)
```

Look wise, it appears to work. However, it no longer thinks the answer is correct and therefore asks me to guess again:

[image: Look wise, it appears to work. However, it no longer thinks the answer is correct and therefore asks me to guess again.]

I am just confused by why this is happening because if I were to print the two variables of which need to be equal for it to be correct, they would be exactly the same. Though the program doesn't think that.

```
for i in range(2):
        guess = input('\nGuess: ')
        if guess == song and triesLeft == 2:
            global score
            score += 3
            print('Correct! Current Score: ' + str(score))
```

In the else statement further on I put: print(guess) print(song):

[image: In the else statement further on I put: print(guess) print(song)]

Thank you for reading all of this and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of terminal output. Include them as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textreading looks suspicious:

```
text = file.readlines()[number]
```

[Doku - hidden in IOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines)

It works similar to readline() in that it:

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

(from [Dok](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

You are never trimming `'\n'` from your title, so its essentially *not* euqal to your input as this one has no '\n' at its end.

You can use `song = song.rstrip()` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)) to remove whitespaces including newlines from it.

For multi-word songtitles you might want to inspect the `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` dokumentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and use it like so:

```
 # create 2 splits maximum
 artist, song = text.split(None, 2) # problem if your artist has 2 words though
```

Comment: Sadly the multi-word song titles won't work because there are instances whereby the artist has multiple words as well as the song name. Also, how do I correctly use rtrim in my code because I am not familiar with it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Arctic typo - I ment rstrip() - its the same as strip() but just on the righjt side of your string. You do not have a "special" divider between artist - name and title of the song - how do you propose to divide both from one another if you only have spaces all over the line? I added a rstrip link for you.

Comment: @Arctic you would use it `text = file.readlines()[number].rstrip()` there ... f.e. or by `text = text.rstrip()`